# RStudio Not Rendering Sankey

Tags: r, data-visualization, sankey-diagram

Looking for some help identifying why this code would not render the Sankey in RStudio viewer or otherwise.  I think it could be a problem with my R version (3.3.1)...the packages I'm using were built under 3.3.1.  Unfortunately my organization takes awhile to update the enterpirse...

```
library(devtools)
library(rjson)
library(igraph)
library(rCharts)

x = read.csv('./R/dataforR.csv', header=TRUE)

colnames(x) <- c("UID","From", "To", "Avg.Hours")

sankeyPlot <- rCharts$new()

sankeyPlot$set(
data = x,
nodeWidth = 115,
nodePadding = 110,
layout = 132,
width = 1500,
height = 1300,
units = "hrs",
title = "New Sankey"
)
sankeyPlot$setLib('http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey')

sankeyPlot
```

Comment: I receive no errors, just a blank space in viewer

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could improve your question. I receive `Error ... cannot open file './R/dataforR.csv': No such file or directory`. Please read [how to provide minimal reproducible examples in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit & improve the question accordingly. A good post usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data & code tries - all copy-paste-run'able in a new/clean R session.

Answer (score 0):

The address in `sankeyPlot$setLib('http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey')` is incorrect.

As per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985967/problems-while-reproducing-sankey-chart-example-with-d3-sankey), it should be:

`sankeyPlot$setLib('http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/libraries/widgets/d3_sankey')`

Comment: Thanks for catching that.